# How to 'clean' InputStream without closing it?

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

Client code snippet. Basically it reads from standard input and sends message to the server.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1200)) {
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (String msg = scanner.nextLine(); !msg.equals("end"); msg = scanner.nextLine()) {
            writer.write(msg + "\n");
            writer.flush();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server code snippet. Prints a message from stream.

```
 public void run() {

    try (InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets
            .US_ASCII)) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int c = reader.read(); c != -1; c = reader.read()) {

            builder.append((char) c);
            if ((char) c == '\n')
                System.out.print(builder);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Input from client:

```
Text1
Text2
```

Server output:

```
Text1
Text1
Text2
```

The problem I am facing that server prints not just received message but also all messages before it.

Question: How can I reset 'clean' `InputStream` without closing it. And if that is impossible what is preferred solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to 'clean' the stream--you just need to reset the buffer after every line. Try something like the following using [`StringBuilder.setLength`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength-int-):

```
if (c == '\n') {
  System.out.print(builder.toString());
  builder.setLength(0);
}
```

On the other hand, I'd strongly encourage *not* manually reading lines like that. Consider using a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) like you do in the client code or alternatively a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

```
try (final BufferedReader reader
         = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII))) {
  for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
} catch (final IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Silly mistake :). Tnx